# Why the spinner position wrong?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout

My first spinner display on the phone would have some strange offset to the top, but in my xml, I can't see what cause this situation.

Can somebody help me to find the root cause?
And my spinner would get some offset, so somebody know what cause this?

Allowed is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/zoomViewIgActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            tools:context=".activity.IgActivityDetailActivity">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/flayour_headicon"
            layout="@layout/layout_person_thumbnail_in_person_page"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="81dp"></include>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_edit_photo"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textview_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview_name"
            android:src="@drawable/editphoto_n" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/flayour_headicon"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_edit_name"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/flayour_headicon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview_name"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_n" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_mail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textview_name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_spinners"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textview_mail"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_age"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:theme="@style/IngoodSpinnerStyle" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_gender"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"

                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:theme="@style/IngoodSpinnerStyle" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_location"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:theme="@style/IngoodSpinnerStyle" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_icon_comment"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_spinners"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:src="@drawable/grade" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_title_comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_spinners"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_icon_comment"
            android:text="@string/title_comment_grade" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_icon_about_me"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageview_icon_comment"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
            android:src="@drawable/host" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_title_about_me"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageview_icon_comment"
            android:layout_marginTop="74dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_icon_about_me"
            android:text="@string/title_about_me" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_content_about_me"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textview_title_about_me"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_icon_about_me"
            android:text="@string/title_about_me" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview_edit_about_me"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageview_icon_comment"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
            android:src="@drawable/edit_n" />



                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/top_of_change_pwd"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imageview_edit_about_me"
                            android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorBlack" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textview_change_pwd"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/top_of_change_pwd"
                            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorWarningRed"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:text="@string/btn_change_pwd" />

                        <View
                            android:id="@+id/bottom_of_change_pwd"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imageview_edit_about_me"
                            android:layout_marginTop="114.5dp"
                            android:background="@color/colorBlack" />






                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutIgActivityButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16.5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/zoomViewIgActivity"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_register_next"
            android:text="@string/btn_save"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSlave"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_button_ig_activity" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the display on the phone:
[image: the display on the phone]

Comment: Personally, I would change container for those spinners from `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`. This way it's much quicker for system to draw and most certainly will fix your bug

Comment: align bottom to layout_spinners